# FormatException in application iOS Xamarin(C#)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

In my mobile app (iOS) I have FormatException in this code:

```
    public partial class DetailTovarProsmotr : UIViewController
{

    public JsonValue myjsondetail;
    int count_product;
    float price_defoult;
    public string Code1;

    public DetailTovarProsmotr (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        
    }
    public async Task<UIImage> LoadImage (string imageUrl)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        Task<byte[]> contentsTask = httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync (imageUrl);

        // await! control returns to the caller and the task continues to run on another thread
        var contents = await contentsTask;

        // load from bytes
        return UIImage.LoadFromData (NSData.FromArray (contents));
    }

    public async override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {

        base.ViewDidLoad ();


    //  Console.Out.WriteLine (detailtitle+" ViewDidLoad metod is run" + myjsondetail["ID"].ToString());

        Code1 = myjsondetail ["sku"];

    
        titleproduct001.Text = myjsondetail["post_title"];
        postSingleProduct.Text = myjsondetail["post_excerpt"];
        Weight001.Text = myjsondetail["weight"]+" г";
        price001.Text = myjsondetail["price"]+" грн";
        postImage.Image =await this.LoadImage (myjsondetail["img_url"]);

        count_product = 1;
        countproduct.Text = "1";


        //float price_defoult = float.Parse(price001.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) ;

        price_defoult = float.Parse( ((string)myjsondetail["price"]).Replace(".00", ".0") );



        plus.TouchUpInside += (o,s) => {
            //Console.Out.WriteLine("Нажали плюс!!!!");

            countproduct.Text = string.Format("{0}", ++count_product);
            price001.Text = string.Format("{0}", count_product*price_defoult + "грн");


        };
        mines.TouchUpInside += (o,s) => {

        //  Console.Out.WriteLine("Нажали минусссс!!!!");

            countproduct.Text = string.Format("{0}", count_product > 1 ? --count_product : 1);
            price001.Text = string.Format("{0}", count_product * price_defoult + "грн");


        };

        addToCart.TouchUpInside += (o,s) => {

        
            var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments); 
            var filePath = Path.Combine (documents, "myFile.xml");

            Console.Out.WriteLine("Добавить в корзину!!!!!");
            Console.Out.WriteLine(countproduct.Text);


            //MessageBarStyleSheet styles = new MessageBarStyleSheet ();
            //UIColor colorb = UIColor.Black;
            //styles.BackgroundColorForMessageType(MessageType.Info).GetWhite;

        
            //  style.BackgroundColorForMessageType = UIColor.Black;
            MessageBarManager.SharedInstance.ShowMessage ("Товар добавлен ", "в корзину", MessageType.Info);

            //Posrednic singleprod = new Posrednic(myjsondetail);
            CartProduct cart = new CartProduct();
            int productQty = int.Parse(countproduct.Text);

            for (int i = 0;  i< productQty; i++) {
                cart.Add(myjsondetail.ToString());
            }

            CartProduct.PrintProducts(cart);
            //singleprod.myjsondetail =myjsondetail;

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);


            var product = new XElement("Product", new XAttribute("Code", Code1), new XAttribute("Qty", countproduct.Text));
            var products = doc.Descendants("Products").First(); // Get the first Products node.  Throw an exception if not found.
            products.Add(product);

            File.WriteAllText(filePath, doc.ToString());
            doc.Save (filePath);
            Console.WriteLine("Smotri tut");

            Console.WriteLine (doc.ToString());



        };




    }
}
```

I think my problem in this line

```
price_defoult = float.Parse( ((string)myjsondetail["price"]).Replace(".00", ".0") );
```

but I don't now where my problem. In simulator my code is working, but in iphone 5s I have:

> FormatException Input string was not in a correct format. (mscorlib)
>
> SIGABRT Crash in System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncMethodBuilderCore__ThrowAsyncm__0_object
>
> SIGABRT Crash in System_Xml_XmlTextReaderImpl_Read

Comment: Maybe the simulator is using another culture than your device and while the simulator matches the replace pattern ".00" the device comes with values like "123,00" (notice the comma) which cannot be replaced and parsed. Just a guess ...

Comment: Can you include the actual value of myjsondetail["price"].Replace(".00", ".0") from both the simulator and the real device?

Comment: this code 'Console.WriteLine (((string)myjsondetail["price"]).Replace(".00", ".0"));' print  122.0 @DylanS

Comment: I modified my code on 'price_defoult = float.Parse( ((string)myjsondetail["price"]).Replace(",", ".").Replace(".00", ".0") );'
but results is FormatException

Comment: as @Waescher pointed out earlier, if your device is using a different locale than your simulator, it may not accept a "." as a valid decimal delimiter in a float.  Have you actually checked that?

Comment: Thanks, I'm solwed my problem, read my answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm solved my problem:

delete line 6 `float price_defoult;`

in line `price001.Text = myjsondetail["price"]+" грн";` deleting  `+" грн"`

use this line `float price_defoult = float.Parse(price001.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` for bringing type.